# What's wrong with Nginx location match rule

Tags: nginx

I do read the Nginx documentation about location matching.
I know about the prioriy of modifier.

And here is my config.

```
    location = /login {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/mysite;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location = / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/mysite;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~ /(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1;
    }
```

What I want is when I type "http://example.com/" "http://example.com/login" , the request will goes index.html which is a React App , and other request will goes proxy pass to my Tomcat application which is bind 8080 port.

But "http://example.com/" "http://example.com/login" request goes proxy_pass , what?

According to Nginx documentation, the "=" modifier is "Priority one"
I expect it is an exact match.

> If an exact match is found, the search terminates

I also use https://nginx.viraptor.info/ test for it.

It shows what I expected.

But it looks like the running server not act what Nginx doc said.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of a `try_files` statement is special. It can be a status code, a named location, or the URI of an internal redirect. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

In your current configuration, Nginx generates an internal redirection to `/index.html` and restarts the search for a matching `location`. So the `/index.html` request is sent to the `proxy_pass`.

Place `/index.html` before the last parameter so that it's interpreted as a *file* parameter and is processed within the same `location` block. The `$uri` is unnecessary in this particular case.

For example:

```
root  /usr/share/nginx/mysite;

location = /login {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

The `=404` will never be reached. The final `location` can be simplified and the capture is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks ,  404 does end the search for matching.