# Nginx can't use second location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to serve two static flat html files , but my location settings are only ever resolving into one.
When I go to myurl.com/a/b it always serves up a.html.

The first thing I tried was nesting the /a/b location as according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/627309),

```
location /a/ {
 location /a/b {
  try_files /b.html
 }
 try_files /a.html
}
```

but only ever got a.html.

I then added the `^~` according to [this location priority question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority) thinking /a/b would get matched first, but it's still not.

```
location ^~ /a/b {
  try_files /b.html;
 }
 location /a/ {
  try_files /a.html;
 }
```

In the comments there was a link to https://nginx.viraptor.info/ , and if I copy the ^~ attempt into there the result is:

```
Final Match:
Location: /a/b
Match type: priority prefix
```

Both of these I also attempted with and without the `$uri` and `$uri/`, ex:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ XX.html
```

Some lines from my Nginx log files which I think are relevant:

```
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 http uri: "/a/b/"
...
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 test location: "/"
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 test location: "a/"
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 test location: ~ "/\.ht"
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 using configuration "/a/"
...
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 trying to use file: "/a.html" "/var/www/html/a.html"
[debug] 1222#1222: *10775 try file uri: "/a.html"
```

I then tried using an exact match according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63933197/2927366), but still my result is a.html

```
 location = /a/b/ {
  try_files /b.html =404;
 }
 location /a/ {
  try_files /a.html =404;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

If both your static files a.html and b.html are located in one place. You need only one location to serve requests /a/ and /a/b:

```
location / {
   root ... ;
   try_files $uri =404;
   rewrite /([^/]+)/$ /$1.html last;
}
```